How can I remove and re-add a click listener in Svelte?
<div on:click={handleClick}>Click here</div>

Sometimes I want the div to be clickable, and sometimes I don't. How can I remove and add the click listener on demand?
This is the workaround that I used and it's working for now, but I feel like there must be a more elegant or sveltelcious way of doing it.
let disabled = false;

function handleClick() {
  if (disabled) return;

  // do stuff otherwise
}


You should not have click events on divs at all, use a button.

There are many scenarios where you need click events on a div or another element. A button isn't always the best solution. For example,  being able to click a card.

I do not see any reason why a card cannot be a button.

There are some other ways, like putting the condition in the template, but ultimately you will need a flag somewhere (unless you do direct DOM interactions which is not recommended).
<button on:click={clickEnabled ? onClick : undefined}>...

REPL
This could also be done via a higher order function in a store or reactive variable, then you would get something like:
<button on:click={clickEnabled(onClick)}>...

REPL
The function then either returns the handler or undefined. If the handler and condition are defined locally, that could also be combined into just one reactive variable directly.
$: onClick = !condition ? undefined : e => {
  // logic
}

REPL
Whether any of that is better than just returning from the handler is debatable.
(And as noted, do not attach such events to non-interactive elements, it's inaccessible.)
